# Scroll event detection in qt

Tags: qt, scroll, mouse

How do I detect a scroll event in a Qt widget?.
 I want to use it to scroll a QWT plot. I have tried using a `QMouseEvent`, but I could only find options for movement and pressing/releasing the mouse.

Comment: Do you mean mouse wheel events?  Scrolling is what scroll bars do.

Comment: that is indeed what I ment. I want to recieve a signal when het mousewheel is moved

Comment: Well you won't get a signal because the mouse is not represented by a `QObject`, but the widget under the mouse cursor will receive an event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`void QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)` will be what you are after (docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#wheelEvent)).

Answer (score 9):

If you use vertical wheel mouse, you can catch wheel up or wheel down event using the below function. If you use horizontal wheel mouse, check `ev->angleDelta().x()` value!

```cpp
void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev->angleDelta().y() > 0) // up Wheel
        action1();
    else if(ev->angleDelta().y() < 0) //down Wheel
        action2();
}
```